# How to fully customize the Android AppBar?

Tags: android, material-design, uitoolbar, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I would like to implement an AppBar, in my application, in a way similar to what Airbnb did:

[image: Airbnb toolbar]

So: actionable icons equally distributed horizontally, no title, but a navigation drawer which is opened by clicking the icon on the right.

Do you think it's better for me to use the `Toolbar` widget introduced some time ago, and heavly customize it, or to simply write something ad-hoc using the standard `RelativeLayout`?

The problem is that this pattern is quite far from the Material Design specs, and I fear it might be difficult to use the `Toolbar` object. On the other hand, I would like not to waste a lot of time implementing something ex novo...

Since I've almost no experience in developing UIs which diverts from official guidelines, I would really appreciate to know your point of view on the matter.

Comment: For that, you need to use the [`TabLayout` component](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) introduced in the Android Design Support Library.

Comment: You can achieve that using a Toolbar with a TabLayout inside. But, if you dont need any of the features provided by the Action bar such as up navigation, menus or action modes then you won't miss much if you use a layout in place of it.